# Controller on One system wishes to send data to controller on another system

Tags: ruby, controller

I have a ruby on rails app on one system ( with ipaddress ip_a ) and the same code running on another system ( with ipaddress ip_b )

Thus, both have a model called `Grid`

I wish to update the `Grid` model of ip_a with ip_b `Grid` Model's information.

How can I achieve this ?

I have tried directly updating the `Grid` models using establish connection of ActiveRecord. 
I am wondering if i can send a object from the controller of ip_a to the controller of ip_b through post.

Anyone know how to go about this 
?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's best solution, but you can use [JSON](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data) for that.
So for example:

grids_controller.rb

```
def sync
  grid = Grid.find(params[:id])
  if grid
    client = HTTPClient.new
    json_params = client.get_content("http://your_ip_b_url/grid/#{params[:id]}.json")
    grid.update_attributes(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json_params))
  end
  respond_to do |f|
    f.js #in sync.js.erb you just modifying your index.html.erb to show that action is completed
  end
end

def show
  grid = Grid.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |f|
    f.json { render :json => grid}
  end
end
```

and in your index.html.erb you just create a link to sync action in @grids listing which could be remote.

Of course you'll need to refactor that, and probably change few things, but i think it's a start.